# What is the difference between /ɪ/ and /ə/?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, ipa

Is there any difference between the /ɪ/ and /ə/ sounds? For example, for "listen", is there any problem with pronouncing it like /ləsən/ instead of /lɪsən/?

Comment: I think the contrast you have in mind is that between /ɪ/ and /ɛ/.  The notation /ə/, the 'schwa', is ordinarily used for the 'neutral' vowel which occurs in unstressed syllables.

Answer (score 2):

/ə/ is typically only used in unstressed syllables.  In *listen*, the first syllable is stressed, so the vowel *i* cannot be pronounced /ə/ .  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa for more information.

Also, if you are not careful with the pronunciation of the *i* in *listen*, people may think you are saying [*lessen*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lessen).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the title:

**/ɪ/** is a 'front vowel', meaning the front part of the tongue is raised while articulating this vowel. It's also a 'close vowel'. A close vowel is one where the jaws come close to each other. The closest vowel in English is **/i/** (/iː/), where the jaws are closer to each other than in /ɪ/. So the difference between /ɪ/ and /iː/ is not only that of length, but vowel quality. /ɪ/ is also 'unrounded' i.e. the lips aren't rounded.

**/ə/** on the other hand is a 'mid vowel' it means that the jaws aren't closer to each other. It's also a 'central vowel'. A central vowel means the central part of the tongue is raised while articulating this vowel. It's often unrounded, I don't think it's rounded version exists. It's a very lazy sound with the mouth partially opened.

Here's the vowel chart:

> > [image: Vowel chart]
>
> <sub>From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel)</sub>

You can see that /ə/ is at the centre of the chart while /ɪ/ is at the front, a tiny bit lower than /i/ and a tiny bit closer than /e/.

Here's what David Crystal says about /ɪ/ in *The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language*:

> Part of tongue nearer centre than front raised to just above half-close position; lips loosely spread; tongue lax; rims make light contact with upper molars

And about /ə/:

> Centre of tongue raised between halfclose and half-open; lips neutrally spread; no firm contact between rims and upper molars.

> for "listen", is there any problem with pronouncing it like /ləsən/ instead of /lɪsən/?

Yes, because the first syllable of 'listen' has primary stress and it's highly unlikely to find /ə/ in stressed syllables, as noted in Nate's answer. In order to pronounce 'listen' as /ləsən/, you will have to say it slowly without stressing any syllable and it will sound very unnatural. The second syllable, however, is unstressed and has a schwa /ə/.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with your pronunciation. If you say /lessen/ with two weak e-sounds it is not clear whether you mean a lesson or to lessen or to listen. Communication with you might become difficult. To listen is pronounced as / lisn/ and you should believe was IPA says.

Answer (score 0):

In New Zealand, the vowels have shifted. You may indeed hear /ləsən/

I'm not aware of any other variety of English where this is true.

In the following article "Fush and Chups" refers to the food item "Fish and Chips". It is pronounced, "[Fəsh and Chəps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORu5Rlna6Lg)"

> The New Zealand Accent: More Than ‘Fush And Chups’
> https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/new-zealand-accent

Comment: I beg to differ with your answer. You can never hear "/ləsən/", unless you speak really slowly and don't stress any syllable. In the video you linked, there's definitely stress. /ə/ cannot occur in a stressed syllable.

Comment: *"/ə/ cannot occur in a stressed syllable"*  -   Yes it can. It's just a vowel sound and it is perfectly possible to stress it like any other. In various parts of England a simple word like "but" can have many different vowel sounds. If you travel from South to North, you can hear a gradual change as you go. In some places people say "/bət/" and I've certainly heard "books" pronounced as "/əks/".

Comment: I know how vowels work in various parts of England, but you're misunderstanding. Schwa /ə/ by definition is an unstressed vowel. It's not just a vowel and can be stressed like any other vowel. The stressed version would, however, be /ʌ/ (or /ɐ/ in some accents).

Comment: @Void - Quote: *"In New Zealand English, the high front lax vowel (as in the word bit /ˈbɪt/) has shifted open and back to sound like schwa, and **both stressed and unstressed schwas exist**. To a certain extent, that is true for South African English as well."*   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa

Comment: That's weird...