# What's the difference between /ɜ/ and /ə/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels

Someone said, one is k.k sound mark, and another is international sound mark.
Then, I find this

> [image: screenshot of 'fervor']

They are both in one phonetic system. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ɜː] and [ə] are phonetic symbols representing 2 absolutely different sounds.

**[ə]** is called [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), which is a very short neutral vowel sound. We hear it at the end of the word "moth**er**", "fath**er**", "teach**er**" etc. (generally, if the accent of the speaker is not American because Americans often add "r"): ['mʌð**ə**], ['fɑːð**ə**], ['tiːʧ**ə**].

**[ɜː]** can be heard in "b**i**rd" [b**ɜː**d], "h**u**rt" [h**ɜː**t], "h**ea**rd" [h**ɜː**d].

See the phonetic chart below:

[image]

Comment: "if the accent of the speaker is not American because Americans add "r"" More precisely, rhotic dialects have an r. There are non-rhotic Americans and rhotic Britons. And it's a bit weird to say that Americans "add" an r, when the spelling implies that the standard form has an r.

Answer (score 5):

Both /ɜ/ and /ə/ are [IPA symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels). The key difference between /ɜː/ and /ə/ (schwa) is that /ɜː/ chiefly occurs in stressed syllables while /ə/ occurs in unstressed syllables at least in British English (I can't speak for American English). There's also a length difference<sup>**1**</sup> between /ɜː/ and /ə/. [**ː**] signifies vowel length. In RP, /ɜː/ occurs in the word *b**i**rd*, while /ə/ in the first syllable of ***a**bout*

If you look at the vowel chart, you will see that both /ɜ/ and /ə/ are in the 'central' position:

> > [image: Vowel chart]

It means they are both central vowels. Central vowel is one in which the central part of the tongue body is raised towards the roof of the mouth.

/ə/ is located at the very centre of the vowel chart; central and mid. A mid vowel is one in which the tongue is positioned midway between an open vowel (like the vowel in *cat*) and a close vowel (the vowel in *seat*). So the mouth is neither too open, nor too close while articulating /ə/.

/ɜ/ is located a tiny bit lower than /ə/, meaning the mouth is a bit more open while articulating /ɜ/, so we can say /ɜ/ is 'open-mid' vowel. An open-mid vowel is one in which the tongue is positioned one third of the way from an open vowel to a close vowel. But this distinction is incomprehensibly minuscule.

The first syllable of 'fervour' is stressed so it has /ɜː/, while the second syllable is unstressed and has /ə/. [Also note that it's the pronunciation of 'fervour' in non-rhotic accents (RP), in rhotic accents, the first syllable would have r-coloured /ɜː/ i.e. /**ɝː**/]

(I've also explained the difference between /ɪ/ and /ə/ in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271471/106592) and between /ʌ/ and /ə/ in [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270716/106592).)

<sup>**1**. The difference is not only length, but that of 'quality'. As can be observed in /iː/ and /ɪ/. /iː/ is the vowel in 'beat' while /ɪ/ in 'bit', so the vowels in those words are qualitatively distinct from each other.</sup>

Comment: The difference in quality depends very much on the speakers' accent — in several dialects, the difference in quality is minimal, if it exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what author Gerald Kelly says about the two phonemes in his book (**How to Teach Pronunciation**):

1. *For both phonemes, /ə/ and /ɜː/, the center of the tongue is between the half-close and half-open positions (The 'close' position is where the tongue is closest to the roof of the mouth). Lips are relaxed, and neutrally spread.*
2. */ə/ differs from others phonemes, in that its contrast with similarly articulated long sound /ɜː/ does not involve a change of meaning.*

Comment: No change in meaning? What about [foreword](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/foreword) and [forward](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/forward).

Comment: I spent the last two days trying to find an example that wasn't  **foreword / forward**. The only one I found was **a / uh**. I think the author's proposal is a good generalization.

Comment: I think *foreword/forward* may be the only one-word example. But you can come up with two-word examples like *clam bird* and *clambered* (and possibly even more plausible ones).

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably /ɜː/ is an allophone of /ə/. 'Bird' /bɜd/ and /ə'baut/ sounds the same for me. On the other hand, the /ə/ in possible /posəbəl/ is another thing. It most certainly is not the same sound as /ə/ in 'bird'.