# When contract "used to" as "usta", is it pronounced /ə/ or /a/?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, vowels

In everyday english, people like contracting words, for example,  "used to" would be contracted as "usta".

When people pronounce a single "usta", it sounds like /juːstah/; when people pronounce a sentence, "usta" sounds like /juːstə/;

Did I hear correctly? Is there some rules for this?

Comment: It's down to the accent of the speaker and how lazy they are when speaking. No rules apply. "Usta" is not an English word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely anecdotal, and not even based on particularly careful observations of my own or others' speech (Australian English, for what it's worth). But I think that /juːsta/ is likely to be found in isolation, sentence-finally, or before other breaks, and /juːstə/ in other positions.

This is not dissimilar to pronunciaton of "to" itself as /tu/ versus /tə/.

With the "usta" contraction:

> I used to swim. /aɪ juːstə swɪm/
>
> Do you swim? I used to. /aɪ juːsta/

Without:

> I used to swim. /aɪ juːst tə swɪm/
>
> Do you swim? I used to. /aɪ juːst tu/

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I guess I got the key, positions! Thank you! Btw, does Australian pronounce that as /aɪ juːstə swɪm/ or /aɪ juːstu swɪm/?

Answer (score 0):

/a/ is an open front vowel, meaning the mouth is open and the tongue is positioned in the front of the mouth. It's one of the cardinal vowels and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel), it's not directly intended to correspond to a vowel sound of a specific language but rather to serve as a fundamental reference point in the vowel chart.

It's often associated with the *TRAP* vowel in RP. You can't use this at the end of *used to*.

*Used to* is often pronounced by native speakers as [juːstə]—with a [**schwa**, which is a mid central vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272320/106592).

> When people pronounce a single "usta", it sounds like /juːstah/

/h/ in the coda (terminal) of English words is forbidden, so you can't have */-tah/.