# Do only Americans pronounce "used to" as /juːstə/ or /juːsta/?

Tags: pronunciation

Another post ([When contract "used to" as "usta", is it pronounced /ə/ or /a/?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238518/109190)) explains why "used to" is pronounced /juːstə/.

This post focus on who pronounce that way.

I've watched lots of American television series, which got me a sense that Americans like contracting words in street spoken English.

To give you an idea, "used to" in this sentence

> I *used to* know a guy like that.

Would be pronounced /juːstə/ or /juːsta/. Do only Americans pronounce this way? or native English speakers in other places like UK, Australia, Canada do the same thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When contract "used to" as "usta", is it pronounced /ə/ or /a/?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238518/when-contract-used-to-as-usta-is-it-pronounced-%c9%99-or-a)

Comment: @JamesK Thanks. That post explains why "used to" is pronounced /juːstə/.

This post focus on who pronounce that way.

Comment: As a Brit, I would say /juːstə/ is commonplace.  It's really nothing to do with this particular phrase IMO.  Pretty much any unstressed vowel in English can end up as ə.  On the other hand I am struggling to think of any case where I would say  /juːsta/.  If I'm pronouncing the o "properly" then it's more /u/ than /a/.  Of course, that is just my accent, in some other accents maybe it's more of an /a/.