# Pronunciation of adjectives ending with "-ate"

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, suffixes

- Legitim**ate**

How should I pronounce it?

It's confusing me. There are so many vocabularies of adjectives ending with "ate"

1. as in m**eet** or as in "it" : like "tim -it"
2. as in **a** boy :    (a boy, a book), not amphasis of a
3. as in m**a**te:     ei

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? Do you know what a ***schwa*** (neutral vowel) is?

Comment: 'Legitimate' is pronounced with a schwa, as FF said in a comment above. If you don't know how to pronounce a schwa, then I've just explained it in an answer to another question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272320/106592).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules for the pronunciation of *-ate* endings that I'm aware of, but here's a general rule of thumb that you can stick to:

**Monosyllables** that end in *-ate* are almost always pronounced /-eɪt/, for example, *mate, fate, rate, sate, date, gate, hate, late* etc.

**Disyllabic and polysyllabic words**:

- Verbs ending in *-ate* are usually pronounced /-eɪt/ as in *hesitate, operate, communicate, accelerate* etc.
- Nouns ending in *-ate* are usually pronounced /-ət/, for example, *chocolate, climate, advocate, estimate* etc.
- Adjectives ending in *-ate* are usually pronounced with /-ət/, for example, *legitimate, approximate, appropriate* etc.

Now some adjectives and nouns I listed above can also be used as verbs, in which case, they're pronounced with /-eɪt/.

- 'Estimate', 'approximate', 'appropriate' etc., are pronounced with /-eɪt/ when used as verbs.

This rule of thumb is fairly consistent.

Comment: 'Monosyllable' -> one-syllable word. 'Disyllable' -> two-syllable word.

Comment: Is *communicate* and *accelerate* disyllabic?

Comment: @Pang: No. Sorry. I had to write **Disyllabic and polysyllabic**. Fixed now.

Comment: Hey wait... what about compound nouns? *roommate/schoolmate/workmate/teammate/soulmate* all end with /-eɪt/. Although the words are disyllabic, I guess the *mate* morpheme is still monosyllabic.

Comment: @Pang: Exactly.