# "Albeit" pronunciation - does any one say it like 'al-bite'?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

This is most likely just a case of me "learning" to pronounce 'albeit' wrong, before I ever heard the word spoken by a native speaker.

Had similar issues with other words in the past, so...

I thought it was pronounced 'al-bite'. It there a chance this pronunciation is actually used somewhere by native speakers or is it just pure nonsense?

Comment: Perhaps ignorant (less educated) people do not know it is a shortening from "all be it". It is not your learning, but rather hearing it from such people and you didn't look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: Cannot tell for sure. Also learning German alongside English might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Albeit* is the contracted form of *all be it*, and is pronounced like *all be it*, /ɔːl ˈbiː ɪt/, not **albite* or **albeet*, though the latter is very common. The vowels /i/ and /ɪ/ are qualitatively distinct from each other; /ɪ/ is pronounced with [lowered tongue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271471/106592).

I'm not aware of any accent that pronounces /-biː ɪt/ as /aɪ/.  And *albeit* is certainly not pronounced with /aɪ/ in standard varieties of English, so pronouncing it *bite* is incorrect in standard Englishes.

Comment: I've never heard *anyone* pronounce it *al-bite*.